# No method `apply` on Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've been trying to track down a weird bug in my (fairly simple) Backbone/Coffeescript code.

When running my application, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<IndexView> has no method 'apply'
```

Here's my router:

```
class window.App.Router extends Backbone.Router
    initialize: ->
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
        $(document).on "click", "a:not([data-bypass])", (evt) ->
            href = $(this).attr "href"
            protocol = this.protocol + "//"
            if href.slice(protocol.length) != protocol
                evt.preventDefault()
                App.navigate(href, true)

    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "artist/:id": "artist",
        "albums/:id": "album"
    }

    index:
        @view = new App.IndexView()
```

And the view:

```
class App.IndexView extends Backbone.View
    template: "index"
    el: $("#container")

    initialize: ->
        @render()

    render: ->
        get_template(@el, @template, @domEvents)

    domEvents: ->
        $("#searchInput").on "change keydown", ->
            if $(this).val().length >= 0
                $("#placeholder").css("display", "none")
            else
                $("#placeholder").css("display", "inline-block")
```

From my testing, it appears that this error goes away as soon as I rid of the `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` line of the code. Unfortunately my application requires pushState, so ridding of this isn't an option.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `->` when you define `index` in your router:

```
class window.App.Router extends Backbone.Router
    #...
    index:
        @view = new App.IndexView()
```

The result is that `new App.IndexView()` is executed while your `App.Router` class is being built and `index` becomes the value of `new App.IndexView()`; also, in this context `@` is the class itself so you end up setting `App.Router.view = new App.IndexView()`. The JavaScript looks like this:

```
Router.prototype.index = Router.view = new IndexView();
```

Then, because of your routes:

```
routes: {
    "": "index",
    #...
}
```

the routing system tries to call `router.index` as a function (using [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to ensure the appropriate calling context) in response to a routing request; but `router.index` is a view instance rather than a function/method so you get your error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<IndexView> has no method 'apply'
```

because you can't call `apply` on a view instance.

Presumably, your `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` triggers the initial routing to `index`.

So fix your class definition to define `index` as a method and try again.

---

As an aside, calling `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` inside a router's `initialize` is a bit bizarre. The [usual process is to call `start` *after* your routers have been created](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start):

> When all of your Routers have been created, and all of the routes are set up properly, call `Backbone.history.start()` to begin monitoring `hashchange` events, and dispatching routes.

So might be starting the history system before all the routing is properly set up and ready to go. This could cause some strange things to happen.

Comment: Wow... That did it... *sigh*

I also moved Backbone.history.start() to a line right after new Router(). Thanks a bunch!